# Java type parameter is not within its bound

Tags: java, generics, comparator, comparable

I have a class Zeitpunkt which implements a date with time and in addition a class Suchbaum which represents a binary search tree.

I want to use a Comparator-Object in Suchbaum to sort a tree by the day of Zeitpunkt, but when I want to create a Suchbaum object, it prints the named error.

**Zeipunkt**

```
public class Zeitpunkt<T> implements Comparable<T>
{
private int jahr;
private int monat;
private int tag;
private int stunden;
private int minuten;
private double sekunden;

public int vergleich(Zeitpunkt a) { ... }

@Override
public int compareTo(T o) {
    if(o instanceof Zeitpunkt)
        return vergleich((Zeitpunkt)o);
    return 0;
}
...
}
```

**Suchbaum**

```
public class Suchbaum<T extends Comparable<T>> {
private class Element {
    private T daten;
    private Element links;
    private Element rechts;

    public Element(T t) {
        daten = t;
        links = null;
        rechts = null;
    }
}
private Element wurzel;
private Comparator<T> comp;
...
}
```

**Testclass**

```
public class BaumTest {
public static void main(String[] args) {

// error in the following line (IntelliJ underlines the first 
// "Zeitpunkt"). Suchbaum<Zeitpunkt<?>> = ... doesn't work either..
// *Completely confused*
Suchbaum<Zeitpunkt> sb = new Suchbaum<>((Zeitpunkt z1, Zeitpunkt z2) -> {
        if(z1.getTag() > z2.getTag())
            return 1;
        else if(z1.getTag() == z2.getTag())
            return 0;
        else
            return -1;
    });
}
}
```

Any ideas? (the other threads with this topic didn't help me out)

Comment: Try and use Englih names in code; this is a generally good habit as it allows  more people to help and/or understand your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems that you don't want to make your `Zeitpunkt` class parametrized, you just want it to implement `Comparable` interface. So change it like this:

```
public class Zeitpunkt implements Comparable<Zeitpunkt> {
    private int jahr;
    private int monat;
    private int tag;
    private int stunden;
    private int minuten;
    private double sekunden;

    public int vergleich(Zeitpunkt a) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Zeitpunkt o) {
        return vergleich(o);
    }
}
```

Also you need to define a constructor in your `Suchbaum` class:

```
public Suchbaum(Comparator<T> comp) {
    this.comp = comp;
}
```